# How do I create a line break in php, after a specified number of characters?

Tags: php, word-wrap, break

How would I write the following in php?

> If number of characters, without a space, exceeds 75, create a line break.

The wordwrap function seems to count whitespace too so I'm not sure I can use that.  I only want to break when my $description is greater than 75 characters and there are no spaces.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to break mid-word?

Comment: Try to write what you need then ask questions when you are stuck.

Comment: If this data is being displayed as an HTML, wouldn't it be better to handle it at the UI level? For example: You can use the word-wrap property is css and set it to "break-word"

Comment: Joseph... yes.  I want to break every 76 characters, regardless of it being mid-word.  Thanks!  @vbuilder..  that's why I'm here.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to break on a space, not just any character.

This is not really efficient but it should work.

```
$array = str_split($input);
$iNumChars = 0;
$sOutput = "";
foreach($array as $char) {
 if($char != " ") $iNumChars++;
 if($iNumChars > 75 && $char == " "){
  $sOutput .=  "\n".$char; 
  $iNumChars = 0;
 }else{
   $sOutput .= $char;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the first `$iNumChars++;`?

Comment: Why not? I have to add it somehwere.. How else am I going to keep count of the no of characters?

Comment: I'm not following your logic. [Check this out](http://www.ideone.com/bTAp0), and compare it to [your version](http://www.ideone.com/sGNRI) (the sample text applies to the 1st version).

Comment: Ah now it see, early morning mistake.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work, try:

```
// $str is your string
$explode = explode(" ", $str);

foreach( $explode as $key=>$val ){
    if( $key <= '75' ){
        $join_arr = " " . $val;

        if( $key == '75' ){
            // Line Break Here
            $join_arr .= "<br>";
        }

        echo $join_arr;
    }
    else{
        exit();
    }
}
```

only provide 76 characters.

Comment: I think this is what I need.  I'll give it a shot tomorrow and let you know.  I've been trying to find a solution for the last hour and it's way past my bedtime now.  :)  Thx!

Answer (score -1):

Find length of string.

if strlen(string) > 75

Search for whitespace in string.(strpos)

if no whitespace found then you can create a line break

Comment: Not a real answer, and she wanted to exclude whitespaces in the count, which you have not accounted for.

Comment: Okk. I correct myseelf. First search for position of whitespace in string. If pos is greater that 75 then create a line break after 75 characters.